# How do I get a Display Name from an Azure ID?

Tags: c#, azure

Working with Azure for the first time. We want to be able to connect requests to our API to the user that made them. With the GraphServiceClient set up, it's easy to get the user information from Microsoft Graph on who made the request to the API:
`graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`

This gives us user information on the authenticated user making the request. We can pull out the ID and store that along with the request information.

The issue comes when we want to display who made the calls. At that point, it would be better to show the human readable Display Name instead of a GUID. So we'd like to call into Azure again with the ID and receive the display name. (And potentially the rest of the user information but for now at least, just the display name will do). In this case, we're not trying to get the information on the authenticated user making the request - we want our service to get display names for a collection of user IDs.

So in short: How do I call Azure to turn an ID into a display name? It seems like the Graph client should be able to do this, but we haven't been able to get it to work.

While we could create a table that stores all the information on the user and fill it when we first get the ID, that's not ideal. We'd just be duplicating information that it seems like we should be able to get from Azure again, and it could go out of date (eg someone changes their name and updates Azure, but our info wouldn't change until they made another request and we fetched it from Azure again)

EDIT

To try to simplify this/get rid of some of the context.

We have a list of some Azure user IDs. We want to use this to retrieve a list of corresponding DisplayNames from Azure. (Possibly we should be storing something other than ID and using that instead, but ID seems like the correct choice)

Comment: "...but we haven't been able to get it to work.": that's quite a vague statement.  What have you tried and what was the result you got?  Do you have any code you could share? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: You're right it's a vague statement. I can't provide the code to do what I want because I can't find an Azure call that does this, but it definitely feels like something that should be doable. If I could provide the code, I would not have a question.

Answer (score 1):

The call you have already has the display name.  You can modify it slightly with Select depending on what fields are needed.  For example, the request below gets the display name and job title.

```
var user = await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .Select(u => new {
        u.DisplayName,
        u.JobTitle
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

user.DisplayName is the property you need in this example.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to store everything I get back in that call. As mentioned, that's duplicating information that's already being stored, and it's liable to go out of date. Rather than keeping that information in a separate table, I'd like to store just one piece of it (the ID) and later use that to call back into Azure to get the rest.

Comment: you realize you need different permissions to lookup ANY users by id...than just looking up the current person?